# possible to disable text-drag in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, drag-and-drop

A feature I despise, which I never use except by accident, is the ability to drag highlighted text.  Sometimes I'll be trying to select a passage, for cut-and-paste, and as I'm dragging the mouse down or across, a chunk of text will be dragged and repositioned accidentally.  Is it possible to disable the text-drag feature?

Comment: That is normally implemented on a per application basis, so I don't think it's possible to turn it off globally. Some applications allow you to disable it, for example Word - [Disable Drag And Drop Text Editing In Word 2007](http://www.lockergnome.com/windows/2007/05/31/disable-drag-and-drop-text-editing-in-word-2007/) and Outlook - [Disable drag and drop of text](http://ccm.net/faq/13590-outlook-disable-drag-and-drop-of-text)